# Concurenncy control mechanism in node.js

Tags: node.js, concurrency

```
const tasks = ...
let concurenncy = 2;
let running = 0;
let completed = 0;
let index = 0;
function next() {
    while (running < concurenncy && index < tasks.length) {
        const task = tasks[index++];
        task(() => {
            if (completed === tasks.length) {
                return finish();
            }
            completed++;
            running--;
            next();
        });
        running++;
    }
}
next();

function finish() {
    console.log('All tasks are done');
}
```

Hello, I have a question about code above. Tasks are array of asynchronous tasks that I need to perform, concurenncy is max number of tasks that can run concurently. Program starts where first two tasks are pulled from array and executed. After one task is over, callback function for that particular task is called. Why I need to call next() method again in that callback? If the callback is finished, won't the loop in the current next method check again if the next task should be taken for processing? Thanks in advance

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score -1):

> Why I need to call next() method again in that callback?

The `while` loop just calls the first N tasks where N is whatever the value of `concurrency` is and then that loop is done and the loop exits because `running < concurenncy` will no longer be true after you've started `concurenncy` number of tasks.

Then, sometime later, one of the tasks will complete and call its callback and your callback that you passed to each task will execute.  If you want to then initiate another task, you have to call `next()` again inside that callback because the `while` loop has already exited.

---

FYI, it seems like you have an issue with your checking of `completed === tasks.length` because you're comparing that BEFORE you count the task that just completed.   Shouldn't you be doing `completed++` BEFORE you compare `completed === tasks.length`?